# Autowiring list of components in spring 4

Tags: spring, list, autowired

I'm trying to autowire list of interfaces this way:

```
@Autowired
private List<SomeInterface<SomeAbstractClass>> list;
```

This is my interface and abstract class:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T extends SomeAbstractClass> 

public abstract class SomeAbstractClass implements Serializable
```

Those are my components (they should end up in the list):

```
@Component("componentA")
public class ImplementationA implements SomeAbstractClass<ClassAImpementingSomeAbstractClass> 

@Component("componentB")
public class ImplementationB implements SomeAbstractClass<ClassBImpementingSomeAbstractClass>
```

And the implementation of abstract class are definied like this:

```
 public class ClassAImpementingSomeAbstractClass extends SomeAbstractClass
 public class ClassBImpementingSomeAbstractClass extends SomeAbstractClass
```

The problem occured after migrating from spring 3.2.5 to 4.3.11.
In spring 3 I'm corecctly getting list that have ImplementationA and ImplementationB. 
After moving to spring 4 I'm getting exception during deployment:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'java.util.List<SomeInterface<SomeAbstractClass>>' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The question is why spring is trying to find bean of typ List? Shouldn't it be trying to find all beans of type SomeInterface and add them to the list (exaclty what I've got on spring 3)?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring changed a lot of things with generics and bean definitions in 4.0 to allow generics to be qualifiers for beans etc.

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

While i'm not 100% sure why this no longer works I assume it now requires you to be slightly more specific in order for Spring to correctly evaluate these qualifiers. (Or something like that)

Either way you should be able to fix it by doing this:

```
@Autowired
private List<SomeInterface<? extends SomeAbstractClass>> list;
```